# Is data transfer between Android applications secure?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I can call other apps' Activities without problem, including sending them some data and receiving some data back. But I am sending and receiving some sensitive information that could arguably be misused if in the wrong hands. My question is, is this data safe when traveling between appications?

For example, I call an Activity like this:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.my.package.MY_REQUEST_ACTION");
            intent.setClassName("com.other.package", "com.other.package.UserActionActivity");
            signerIntent.putExtra("INTENT_PASSWORD", "1234");
            signerIntent.putExtra("INTENT_COMMAND", "COMMAND_DO_SOMETHING");
            signerIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

And return something in UserActionActivity:

```
                Intent result = new Intent("com.other.package.INTENT_RESULT_DESCRIPTION");
                result.putExtra("INTENT_RETURN_RESULT", "...");
                result.putExtra("INTENT_RETURN_RESULT2", "...");
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
                finish();
```

And so on. But how secure are these *extra* strings? Do I have to worry about them being accessible to other applications (other than the two involved), either intentionally or through some kind of "hack"? Do I need something like public key encryption?

And is the situation different on rooted systems (i.e. an app with root privileges can, without too much effort, read inter-app communication)?

Comment: If the data is secure then encrypt that.

Comment: nothing unencrypted is secure on rooted systems. And even on non-rooted systems I'd not expect that data to be secure. You definitely want to encrypt that data.

Comment: You need to encrypt all the sensitive data for all exchange, even if it's between activities or api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to worry about them being accessible to other applications (other than the two involved), either intentionally or through some kind of "hack"?

Let's assume for the moment that neither app has been modified by an attacker.
If so, then in principle, the communications that you have established should be private on non-rooted device. In practice, there have been bugs with activity `Intent` extras, though none that I know of recently. Of your IPC options, activities are probably the worst choice from a security standpoint, as they have other impacts (e.g., appear in the overview/recent-tasks screen) that increase the likelihood that there is some bug that we have overlooked.

In your code, though, both sides assume that the other app has not been modified. In particular:

- Unless you have some security that is not shown, any app on the device can run the code in your first snippet and try to trick the app to return the response in the second snippet.
- The code in your first snippet assumes that `com.other.package` has not been modified by an attacker.

There are ways to help defend against this (e.g., custom `signature` permissions, checking the signature at runtime).

Also, bear in mind that an attacker can find `"1234"` without much difficulty.

With regards to the comments advising encryption, given the protocol that you are describing, encryption seems like an unlikely solution. If you have to provide a secret (`INTENT_PASSWORD`) *in the IPC protocol*, then there is no shared secret that both apps would have to use for encryption purposes, and I'm not quite certain what public-key infrastructure you would use to offer public-key encryption here.

> And is the situation different on rooted systems (i.e. an app with root privileges can, without too much effort, read inter-app communication)?

Absolutely. On a rooted device, all bets are off. That is not tied specifically to IPC, though.

Comment: I am also not sure how to go about the encryption, therefore this question (and maybe a topic for another one). Regarding the rooted system, I woud not be so pessimistic, it would.be bad if the attacker took over the system, but I was looking for something when the user is rational and installs only what he can trust. Now that I think about it I suppose it is no different than normal system. By the way the password was just an example.

Comment: Regarding the IPC options,I thought this is the only one to pass data to the activity (and launch it), or do I have another one?

Comment: @comodoro: Starting an activity does not require passing data via extras. There are other IPC options (sending broadcasts, starting services, binding to services, talking to a `ContentProvider`, etc.). Using extras is convenient but not required.

Answer (score 0):

short answer: it is not safe but it needs some effort for the attacker.

long answer:
the transfer can be intercepted by a man in the middle attack:

on unrooted phones:

if you send data to `intent.setClassName("com.other.package", "com.other.package.UserActionActivity");` somone can uninstall the original "com.other.package" and install his  own "com.other.package" with the same activity that receives the unencrypted data.

For example an attacker can disassemble the original software, add code (that does something with the secret data) and reassemble the code to a new apk (with a different certificate)

On rooted devices: I donot know but i assume it is possible that the "exposed framework" is capable to intercept and redefine android os calls.

Comment: I don't think I need to worry about that particular attack, I assume the user here the "good" party, although of course he could be tricked into doing it. But the system in the case of reinstalling would just reset the communication, no?